# Why my D3D9 Font is poor quality

Tags: c++, fonts, directx, directx-9

I have a question. I'm trying to draw on my screen with DirectX 9, but for some reason **ALL** fonts (which use rounded edges) that I try to use are in poor quality, this also includes fonts downloaded from the internet, I do not know if I'm doing anything wrong, or if I'm just paranoid about it.

Images:

[image: 2 fonts, Windows font and custom internet font]

with 500x zoom:
[image: with 500x zoom]

My create font code:

```
D3DXCreateFont(pDevice, 30, 0, FW_BOLD, 1, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, "Roboto", &pFont);
```

I've tried many things, like:

```
FW_BOLD to FW_SEMIBOLD
DEFAULT_QUALITY to ANTIALIASED_QUALITY
```

but nothing has shown result.

My DrawString function:

```
void D3D9Draw::String(int x, int y, DWORD Flag, int FontID, D3DCOLOR Color, std::string String, ...)
{
    char Buffer[256];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, String);
    vsprintf_s(Buffer, String.c_str(), args);
    va_end(args);

    if (FontID >= (int)m_Font.size())
        FontID = 0;

    RECT Rect = { x, y, x, y };
    m_Font[FontID]->DrawText(NULL, Buffer, -1, &Rect, Flag | DT_NOCLIP, Color);
}
```

btw, sorry for my bad eng.

Comment: Anti-aliasing fail, it thinks the background is black.  Screenshots are a lousy way to show a bug in the code.

Comment: the code is too big to post everything, I do not know why the anti-aliasing has problem for drawtext, it works perfectly with D3DXCreateLine

Comment: what flags did you pass to ID3DXSprite::Begin?

Comment: Also remember, you don't want to scale those fonts as they are not vector graphics font but rasterized

Comment: @Asesh i dont use ID3DXSprite::Begin to draw text, i use ID3DXFont::DrawText, i will post mt DrawString function: https://pastebin.com/M6rPzPhP

Comment: You better use ID3DXSprite and call that DrawText method within ID3DXSprite::Begin/End pair. Specify this flag: D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND and/or one or more flags for that method. That should solve your problem. I remember facing that same problem but after using sprites, it was fixed. Well, that was long time back

Comment: And maybe don't use legacy DIrect3D 9 or ``ID3DXSrite`` at all... See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started)'s ``SpriteBatch`` / ``SpriteFont``.